# Need help converting date data from csv(m/d/Y) to Y/m/d(writing it to another csv)

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv that has a series of dates in it. I've taken the dates and moved them into an array($data). Specifically the data for the dates are $data[0]. I'm trying to convert them from the m/d/Y way to the UTF (Y/m/d) while writing that data to another csv(which will be the target for inserting into a db). Here's what i've tried to far:

```
$dt = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($data[0]));  //Didn't work
//Then i tried this:
$dt = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('m/d/Y', $data[0]);
$dt = $dt->format('Y/m/d');
```

The second function doesn't work as i get an error: "Call to a member function format() on boolean".
I'm not sure why i'm getting that error. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Adding code to show the writing to csv. **This isn't every single possible line i used but as a quick note I'm using glob to put files into an array(csvs)**.

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        preg_match("/^.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).-.([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*/", $file, $matches);

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            if($data[0] != preg_match("/^.*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}).*/", $file))
            {
                $num = count($data);
                $row++;
                if(!file_exists($filename))
                {
                    $newFile = fopen($filename, "w");
                     fputcsv($newFile, $headers);                          
                }
                if(strlen($data[0]) == 9 || strlen($data[0]) == 10)
                {
                    $dt = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('m/d/Y', $data[0]);
                    $dt = $dt->format('Y/m/d');
                }else{
                  $dt = $data[0];
                  echo "Something went wrong. Check the csv";
                    }

                fputcsv($newFile, [$defaults[0], $defaults[1], $defaults[2], $defaults[3], $defaults[4], $defaults[5], $defaults[6], $defaults[7],$defaults[8],$dt, $data[1], $data[4], $data[14], $data[7], $data[2], $data[3], $data[5], $data[6]]);      
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($newFile);
}
```

Basically what this does is match files that have a date range in their name, store that date range in matches, check the specific rows to see if a row to find the m/d/Y row to start placing data in the new csv. Again its not every possible line of code but i think this would give you a good idea of what im doing. In the fputcsv you can see $dt there instead of `data[0]`.

Comment: `DateTime::CreateFromFormat()` returns `FALSE` if the input doesn't match the format. Check `$data[0]` and make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: Ok, i had actually like a dummy wrote 'Y/m/d' for the CreateFromFormat(). I fixed it to the way i have it above but it still does nothing. In the new csv file it still outputs m/d/Y. Any idea why?

Comment: Show the code that's writing to the new CSV file.

Comment: I suspect you're just not updating the array with the value of `$dt`.

Comment: edited. Spacing got wildly messed up but everything that's necessary should be there.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if($data[0] != preg_match("/^.*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}).*/", $file))`? `preg_match()` returns a number, not what it matched.

Comment: You never use `$matches` anywhere.

Comment: `strlen($data[0] == 9)` should be `strlen($data[0]) == 9`

Comment: Why are you opening the file every time through the loop? Open it once at the beginning.

Comment: That code ignores the headers from the original csv file and focuses on only the data within that if statement. If i didn't add that, the original headers would get mixed in with the new csv file creating a major shift in cells. That allows there to be only one row of headers with the data immediately following.

Comment: $matches is used for renaming the file. I used the date range that's in matches to rename the file to that specific date range. That again was not included in the update

Comment: Again not included in the code, is the glob function that's pointing to a specific directory. It has an array of files in it, and i'm looping through each file and applying this script to it. There could be 1000+ files and what this script should do is update each one of them with their own unique data and name.

Comment: If you're trying to test if `$data[0]` looks like a date, it should be `if(preg_match('/pattern/', $data[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
                if(strlen($data[0] == 9) || strlen($data[0] == 10))
```

`==` should not be inside the call to `strlen()`. It should be

```
                if(strlen($data[0]) == 9 || strlen($data[0]) == 10)
```

Because of this, you're never going into that `if` block, so it never fixes up `$dt`.

Also, you need to assign `$dt` when this `if` test fails, so you should have:

```
else {
    $dt = $data[0];
}
```

This line also makes no sense to me:

```
if($data[0] != preg_match("/^.*([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}).*/", $file))
```

`preg_match()` returns the number of matches that were found. `$file` is the filename, so this is the number of times a date-like pattern is in the filename. `$data[0]` is the contents of the first field in the CSV -- either a date or the field heading for dates. Unless this field contains a number, it will never be equal to the result of `preg_match()`, so this condition will *always* succeed. If your intent was to skip the heading line, it won't do that, so the new file will contain headings.

If you want to test if the first field contains a date, use:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/', $data[0]))
```

BTW, there's no need for `.*` when matching, it matches anywhere in the string when there's no anchors.

Comment: hmm.... I see what you're saying. I changed the if statement as you suggested but still no luck. Still getting m/d/Y after running the script.

Comment: Peculiarly, I've echo'd the $dt variable and it is in fact being formatted but for some reason when being written into the csv, it reverts back to m/d/Y.

Comment: That's simply not possible. Variables don't revert by themselves. Did you put the echo inside the `if` or after it?

Comment: I think you'll need to post the full code, you probably lost something when trying to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh..... I figured it out. I'm a big fool. Excel is a parser that's just automatically tuning itself to fit the way it would be read when looking at the average excel file(american format). When i look at the data through a text editor, it shows the date formatted the way it should be. That means that with another script i'd be able to target the data properly.